# fastest archives extraction on the same HDD

Tags: archiving, extract

is there a tool to extract big compressed archives using a big memory buffer and alternating read and writes?
(something like FastCopy, but for archives)

For smaller archives using a ramdisk is doable, but for big ones i need an alternative...

Comment: What OS? And what's the archive type?

Comment: Manly 7-zip on Windows...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: as the title says, faster archives extraction on the same HDD. I've found a (tedious) alternative using splitted RAR archives and manually swapping parts to the ramdisk during the extraction...